# Javascript code not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jquery

I'm Using this JavaScript code with JQuery Library, Now this doesn't work in **Google Chrome**, works in **Apple Safari** and **FireFox** (As tested)

```
$(document).on('blur', '#UserNameInput', function(e) {
    //alert ('this')
    if ($(this).val().length < 6 ) {
        $('#UnameCheck').html('That user anme is too short... please try again with something more than 6 Charecters')
        } else {
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(../images/IMG_8485.GIF)');
    $('#UnameCheck').html('Please wait while checking your User Name').css('color', '#F3F').show('fast');   
    var Uname = ($('#UserNameInput').val())
    var data = {     // create object
            l : Uname
        }
    $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    data: data,
    complete: function(){
        $('#UserNameInput').css('background-image', '')
        },
    url:"../php/UserNameCheck.php"
    }).done(function(feedback){
    $('#UnameCheck').html(feedback)
    });
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you running this from the filesystem? Chrome doesn't allow ajax from the filesystem. You need to use a server.

Comment: Does it write anything to the console, or does it seem to do nothing?

Comment: Please provide a better explanation of the problem, "it does not work" is not useful to us.

Comment: Use the developer tools (Ctrl+shft+i) in Chrome and see if there are errors in the Console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, to be complient with Chrome, you need to add the `mouseup` event, or/and `mouseleave` :

```
$(document).on('blur mouseup mouseleave', '#UserNameInput', function (e) {
    //alert ('this')
    if ($(this).val().length < 6) {
        $('#UnameCheck').html('That user anme is too short... please try again with something more than 6 Charecters');
    } else {
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url(../images/IMG_8485.GIF)');
        $('#UnameCheck').html('Please wait while checking your User Name').css('color', '#F3F').show('fast');
        var Uname = ($('#UserNameInput').val());
        var data = { // create object
            l: Uname
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            complete: function () {
                $('#UserNameInput').css('background-image', '');
            },
            url: "../php/UserNameCheck.php"
        }).done(function (feedback) {
            $('#UnameCheck').html(feedback);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `blur` event is incomplete for FF Mac, Saf Win, Chrome Win and Chrome Mac.

As listed in [these event compatibility tables](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/).

Using other complete event listeners like `mouseleave` and `mouseup` will fix the problem.